# Differences between document.onload functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What are the differences between the methods `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` and `window.onload = function() {`?

They seem to both achieve the same thing by waiting for DOM content to load before doing other stuff.